# command function in tkinter does not work properly

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I was trying to implement my first gui in python with tkinter.
I have this function:

```
def clicked():
    if(b2["text"]=="Start Recording"):
        b2["text"]="Stop Recording"
    elif(b2["text"]=="Stop Recording"):
        b2["text"]="Start Recording"
    stt.start_speech_to_text("prove.txt")
```

where stt is a module that I implemented that uses google cloud speech to text library to convert the speach from the microphone into text.

I put this function into a button in this way:

```
b2 = Button(root, text='Start Recording',command=clicked)
```

but when I run the code and I press the button, the program starts with calling the start_speech_to_text function and only when I stop the execution of that function the button changes its label.

How can I solve this issue?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to add a `root.update_idletasks()` or `root.update()` in your `start_speech_to_text` function. The `mainloop` doesn't update/redraw the widgets till it receives the control back from the `start_speech_to_text` function, and hence the update in the label can only be seen after the execution of the function

Comment: Can I insert this command also if the function is in another module?

Comment: you will have to send the reference of your `root` to this module. Only then will it update. But this is a pain to execute (depending on the complexity of your module). Better to run short loops, or enusre that the code returns to the main function every now and again

Comment: Ok, I solved for now. I'll try to improve also the efficiency. Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean with short loops? Where should I put these loops?

Comment: short loops mean that you do not call a function that will block the mainloop for a long time. Rather, break that single function into shorter functions, which ensures that the mainloop can be updated

Comment: I solved using multithreading :)
Probably it's the most elegant way

Comment: make sure that you do not destroy your mainloop thread, while the other is running